# Using 9v 2000mA power supply for pedal using low current

Tags: effects-pedal, effects

I have [Mooer 9V 2000mA](https://www.thomann.de/gb/mooer_pdnw_9v_2a_eu.htm) power supply and pedals, such as MXR Carbon Copy requiring 26mA at 9V or EHX Pog Nano requiring 25mA at 9VDC. Is it safe to use this power supply with these pedals? Is it safe to use this power supply with these power supplies simultaneously (fx using [Mooer Daisy Chain](https://reverb.com/item/316568-mooer-5-way-l-shape-power-supply-daisy-chain-effect-pedal-extender-cable))?

Comment: See also: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/38697/how-to-choose-a-guitar-pedal-power-supply?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the *voltage* rating is correct, it is perfectly safe to use a power supply with a higher *current* rating than you need. The pedals will only take as much current as they actually use.

Of course an over-rated supply may be bigger, heavier, etc, which might make it less convenient to carry around, but it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the swift supply. But then I do not understand, why everyone is using super-expensive power supplies for their pedal boards. If I have 5 pedal, each requiring 9V and say 100mA, can I use a single power supply (such as abovementioned Mooer 9V 2000mA) to charge them all? It costs 10 times less then a regular pedal board power supply with multiple outputs (e.g. Cioks).

Comment: @MaksimSorokin That's a bit of a separate question but the short answer is that the overall voltage and current rating of a power supply is **not** the only important aspects of that power supply. For example, the Voodoo Labs Pedal Power supplies feature transformer isolated outputs, which is more expensive to manufacture and offers different advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if something goes wrong with a higher than specification supply it can probably fry and cook your pedals much better. Thus it is advisable to place a fuse of required strength in line when using overkill. A 5 cent fuse can save a $500 pedal easy.

Comment: Also, bad things might happen if one pedal connects the negative side of the power supply to audio ground and another pedal connects the positive side of the power supply to audio ground.

Comment: Another reason for using more expensive power supplies is that some of them provide much better filtering of 50/60Hz hum than cheaper supplies. Cheap switchmode supplies can also insert a lot of higher frequency buzz into the audio chain, which isn't ideal.

Comment: The hum is likely to be 100Hz/120Hz as power supplies delivering higher currents would most likely use full wave rectification.  Earthing one side of the 9V DC or allowing both +ve and -ve sides to float together is important in stage set-ups where different power supplies and earths have the potential to interact in a range of technical ways.  Solving these problems under time pressure of a gig without electrocuting a band member is what the sound engineer gets paid for.

Answer (score 3):

If the supply has a voltage regulator it is safe, and store-bought power supplies usually do (and I'd guess this one does). However, some cheap power supplies (mostly ones that come with a particular piece of equipment) depend on the resistance of whatever you're plugging into it to regulate the voltage, so connecting a device with lower current draw could cause the supply to produce considerably more than 9 volts. I fried a scan converter this way once.

[See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply#Functional) (emphasis mine):

> For example, a regulated power supply is one that maintains constant output voltage or current despite variations in load current or input voltage. Conversely, the output of an unregulated power supply can change significantly when its input voltage **or load current** changes."

Answer (score 0):

Your power supply should deliver 9v to all of your pedals. The only thing you should worry about is overloading the power supply. If the sum of all your 9v pedal's current ratings exceeds 2000 mA, then you could have a problem. It doesn't sound like you will ever have that problem. At 25 mA per pedal, you would have to try to power 80 pedals to reach 2000 mA (2 amps).

If you tried to use your 9v power supply with a pedal with a different voltage rating, that would be bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same power supply (which doesn't provide several potential-separated outputs) with several pedals simultaneously, you get ground loops.  It depends on the overall size of your setup and the magnetic fields in its placements whether this will or will not buy you significant levels of hum.