# Standard effect pedal connector/barrel size?

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal, electronics, effects

I use the regular 9V DC negative center power adapter, and every so often the connector gets ripped or the internal soldering wears off and in middle of a gig the adapter stops working.
It usually happens at the connector (barrel) side (see following fig):

[image]

What I had in mind is buy a heavy duty cable and solder it myself to the adapter so it's more durable, plus having an external power cord to the adapter so if I need extended length it's the power cord rather than the adapter cord.

## TL;DR

What's the size of the connector in standard (i.e. Boss) 9V DC adapters? Here are some examples, looks like it's the 5.5*2.5, but maybe it's not even in this list.

Please disregard the other side of the connectors in the picture below. All I'm interested to know is the size of the connector (to the left).

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You might be better soldering straight to the internal socket, and taking a cable out through a small hole you make, so the socket is still available. Open the pedal and hardwire to the socket itelf. that way, basic options are still available

Comment: That's what I'm planning to do, but I need the right connector and I'm not sure what's the size of it.

Comment: No. I mean solder inside, so the connector isn't involved.

Comment: The Voodoo Lab pedal power manuals will have this info. I’ll come here and quote it later if you haven’t found it before then. It’s not only the outer diameter but also the inner diameter that counts.

Comment: @Tim solder inside isn't an option. I'm dealing with multiple FX.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, thank you - the info was [right there](http://www.voodoolab.com/pedalpower_2.htm) (see at the table under _Output_), please post as answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: You can post it as your own answer if you want. Definitely I think you should keep the question. It’s a pretty good one.

Comment: I suspect you use several on stage, daisychained up. If they're all separate, and get bundled away at the end, there's way too much handling going on. That apart, the pots get knocked and twisted in the gigbag. Far better to obtain a case where they all sit happily protected and no need to touch the plugs/wires at all. Cases are available, or build your own, even put the power supply in there as well. An old briefcase was adapted for some of mine. Foam helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Todd Wilcox](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/6070/todd-wilcox) referenced in [his comment](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/75609/standard-effect-pedal-connector-barrel-size?noredirect=1#comment121941_75609), the standard barrel used in FX is of:

### 5.5 x 2.1 mm

Answer (score 2):

OK, so it's 5.5 x 2.1 mm.

But don't.  When there's a plug-and-socket connection that is vulnerable to getting 'ripped', the answer isn't a heavier plug.  That just ensures that when it IS ripped, more damage gets done, probably to the socket.

Mount your pedals on a board, tether the cables so strain will never be placed on the plug/socket interface.

Comment: It's not the plug that gets damaged, it's the connection to the cable between the barrel and the wire. But you definitely got a point.